# In which condition the onDraw method of View to be called repeatedly in Android?

Tags: android

I implement a view by myself, the onDraw method of the view is called repeatedly. This will cause a serious performance problem. The code is so complex that I can't paste here. Anyone can tell me some possible reasons? I haven't touch the view by my finger.

Comment: Post your code is the best way to solve the problem. :)

Comment: The project which contains nearly 70,000 lines of codes was written by other guys. So I haven't paste the code. Really sorry. It won't happen next time.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes. The question is perfectly reasonable--basically asking for ideas about how to diagnose the problem. It's certainly much better than posting a gigantic code dump (see [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/156967)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason would be that your `onDraw` method is calling some method that (perhaps indirectly) invalidates the view. Another possibility is something completely unrelated in your program is causing the repaints. Try this experiment: comment out your drawing code and substitute something really simple, such as a simple line draw, just to show that it's working. If the repeated drawing goes away, then it's something in your `onDraw` code. Just start restoring the current code a bit at a time until the problem reappears and then you can track it down.

If the problem doesn't go away when you try the experiment, then look somewhere else in your code for something (perhaps a worker thread?) that is invalidating your view.

Comment: It also may be worth searching your code for the invalidate() method or postInvalidate() using Eclipse's search facility (assuming Fang Yeng uses eclipse)

Comment: Kerry and Ted, really thanks for your kind help. And I find the problem is caused by `invalidate()` in wrong place. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I solved it by overriding `invalidate()` in my View subclass:

```
@Override
void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();
}
```

Then I set a breakpoint inside `invalidate()` and waited for it to hit. When it did, I had a stack trace of the call, and the offending caller. Mystery solved in 2 minutes.

If that doesn't work, trying overriding the other invalidate methods in View.